# How to use ffmpeg to extract WAVE_FORMAT_GSM610 file to WAVE_FORMAT_PCM file

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I have a compressed audio file that is WAVE_FORMAT_GSM610 format.

Now I want to open it with python wave module. But wave module only support WAVE_FORMAT_PCM file.

I setup ffmpeg tools. What command can I use to complete this conversion?

Or Is there good way to complete the task?

Thinks.

Comment: With ffmpeg CLI, it's simply `ffmpeg -i infile out.wav`

Comment: Thinks very much Mulvya. It works.